# Attribute is assigned only to last object in list

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build a simple GUI simulator for a PLC application in Python (2.7) using Tkinter. I've created a window with many labels, each representing a boolean bit in the application, and I'm trying to bind a toggle function to each label object, simulating a change of state of the PLC's I/O. To do this I've built a list called `bits` with each item a dict looking something like `{'bit':'input1', 'value':True, 'type':'input'}`.

The problem is that I'm trying to bind a click event on a label to a toggle function for each bit, but my clicks are only binding to the last label in the list of labels.

```
class Bitwin(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, root):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
    self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                              tags="self.frame")

    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

    self.labels=[]
    self.populate()

    for h,i in enumerate(self.labels):
        i.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: toggle(i.cget('text')))
        i.grid(row=h%200, column=int(floor(h/200))+1)

def populate(self):
    for h,i in enumerate(bits):
        lab=tk.Label(self.frame, text=i['bit'], bg='grey',fg='white', width=20)
        self.labels.append(lab)
```

I thought binding the toggle function in a separate loop would do the trick, but no. No matter which label I click, only the last 'bit' is toggled.

Comment: That is because in the `lambda` function, `i` is not referenced until the `<Button-1>` event happens.  By that time, `i` has been assigned to each label, and consequently stopped at the last one.

Comment: You're trying to make something like this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimPyLC ? You can use mine for free (or roll your own if that's more fun!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the binding of `i` in the `lambda` inside the `for` loop is bound lazily. `i` is not bound when the lambda is defined, but when it's called.

You can workaround using default parameter:

```
for h,i in enumerate(self.labels):
    i.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, i=i: toggle(i.cget('text')))  # <--
    i.grid(row=h%200, column=int(floor(h/200))+1)
```

Comment: Thank you! You've revealed a misunderstanding I had with regard to lambda and function callbacks.